# Seaborn scatterplot inverts y-axis on some plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have two sets of data that I am using to create scatterplots.  I use a function to create the plot for each one.  For some reason, the plots for one of the sets displays with the minimum y value at the top of the plot (a flipped image, but the text is not inverted).  The other one displays as expected.

The data are read in from Excel files, and are essentially the same.  As I said, I call the same functions for each data set.

The code that draws the plot is:

```
from scipy.stats.distributions import chi2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

    def mcbf_plot(df, alpha=0.8):
        xval = list(range(len(df)))
        xval_l = [item-0.1 for item in xval]
        xval_r = [item+0.1 for item in xval]
        xlabs = list(df['venue'])
        g = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x=xval, y='mcbof_pe', s=100, color='k')
        plt.plot([xval,xval], [df['ci_mcbof_l'],df['ci_mcbof_h']], color='k')
        plt.plot([xval_l, xval_r], [df['ci_mcbof_l'],df['ci_mcbof_l']],color='k')
        plt.plot([xval_l, xval_r], [df['ci_mcbof_h'],df['ci_mcbof_h']],color='k')
        plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(df), 1.0))
        plt.title('Results by Event')
        plt.xlabel('Event')
        plt.ylabel('Cycles')
        g = g.set_xticklabels(labels=xlabs,rotation=45)
```

This is my script that I run to generate the plot:

```
%matplotlib inline
import os
import glob
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import datetime
import binom.binom as bn 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

hist_ram = pd.read_excel('c:/User/Documents/RAM/historic_ram.xlsx')

bn.mcbf_plot(hist_ram, 0.8)
```

And this is an example of the data:

```
   venue   miles  events  fails mmbof_pe ci_mmbof_l ci_mmbof_h mcbof_pe  \
 0     a  1749.8     416      5   349.96    188.664    719.315     83.2
 1     b   353.3      47     14  25.2357    17.5527    37.3088  3.35714
 2     c  1610.1     288      7  230.014    136.786    413.401  41.1429
 3     d   549.1      83      0     None    341.175       None     None

   ci_mcbof_l ci_mcbof_h
 0    44.8533    171.011
 1    2.33505    4.96324
 2    24.4671    73.9454
 3    51.5708       None
```

Any idea why seaborn/matplotlib would invert one plot but not both (or neither)?

Edited to add: the *None* is what is causing the problem.  Is there another way to indicate that there is no value for a given cell in the data set?  Basically, I want to plot the point estimate and confidence interval for tests with failures, but only the lower confidence limit for a test with no failures.  The data treats the LCL as the LCI value, and sets the PE and UCI to *None*.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add a few example hard-coded data points to your code, such that it could be executed to see the problem live and, of course, the required `import`s and a call of your function, to make it a minimal executable example. BUT, keep it as short as possible.

Comment: Possibly some columns are strings instead of numbers

Comment: @JohanC is very likely correct

Answer (score 3):

@JohanC was correct!  I changed "None" to "math.nan" (and added "import math") now it plots correctly.